# Getting Bootstrap Typehead ajax to work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

A lot of the posts on typeahead use a plugin, even though since 2.1.0 Bootstrap has supported ajax calls for typeahead.

I am unable to make it work for what I need - an ajax call of suggested words, at which point clicking on one yields a redirect.

So eg if you type in "lif" it will query "lif" (REST) to another page, return options (life=>http://life.com, lifealone=>http://lifealone.net, etc), and clicking on life or lifealone will then take you to that respect url it is associated with.

I know I could use jqueryui autocomplete, but I'd prefer to keep it withint Bootstrap's native JS/CSS. Is this even possible?

Comment: I've been using a different library with quite some success; also for redirecting: https://github.com/pwarelis/Ajax-Typeahead

Comment: Yeah I've seen quite a few - using a plugin myself. I'd still rather have it work natively with the included Typeahead.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs to call typeahead manually:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead();
```

You can pass options.  The one you're looking for is source:

```
$('.typeahead'.typeahead({
    source: function(query/*text input value*/,callback/*used for asynchronous update*/) {
    $.get('yourdata.file?q='  + query, function (data) {
        callback(data);
    });
}
});
```

Then you'll need to attach an event handler to your select event.  This isn't handled natively with bootstrap.typeahead but there is a fork which has added this functionality.

https://gist.github.com/1891669